# How do I set the start page in Opera 26

Tags: opera

I feel really stupid to ask such a simple question, but neither Google, nor superuser, nor Opera help gives an answer: is it possible to set a custom start page in Opera? I always use a local file with bookmarks for all my browsers, but I cannot seem to get it done in Opera - there just seems to be no option. There is just the Opera Start Page, and I can put my startpage in there - but that is an extra click every time.

I know there WAS an option to set the start page in older versions, but how the heck do I do it in Opera 26?

Comment: Am I right you just want to specify a certain startpage? Like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BCz0b.png)?

Comment: Yes, but not only on browser startup, also when I open a new tab.

Comment: I should have made that clear in the Question, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[New Tab Start Page Pro](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/new-tab-start-page-pro/?display=en) Extension will help you to open that Custom Page in "New Tab" instead of the Start Page.

Comment: Always welcome @Roemer...